# Cloud Composer Parallelism issue DAG and Tasks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have created simple DAG using Bash Operator and BigQuery operator, there are approx 40 BigQuery tasks, I want to execute all 40 BigQuery task to execute parallel, only 10-15 tasks are executing parallel, I have tried with different Configuration parameters.

I also also need to execute 15-20 same kind of DAG, I need to execute all DAGs to execute parallel, all tasks from all DAGs.

**My DAG is like**

start >> bigquery task_1 >> end

start >> bigquery task_2 >> end

... ... ... ... ... ... ...

... ... ... ... ... ... ...

start >> bigquery task_n.. >> end

start and end is bash operator

**My composer configuration as below:**

Image version: composer-1.13.3-airflow-1.10.12
Python version: 3
Worker nodes"
Node count: 3
Disk size (GB): 50
Machine type: n1-standard-2

I have tried with default Airflow configuration and well as below custom configuration and don't see much improvement.

**custom configuration 1**

parallelism = 300

dag_concurrency = 60

max_active_runs_per_dag = 15

enable_xcom_pickling = False

sql_alchemy_pool_recycle = 570

store_serialized_dags = False

min_serialized_dag_update_interval = 30

dag_concurrencymax_active_runs_per_dag = 60

**custom configuration 2**

parallelism = 230

dag_concurrency = 46

max_active_runs_per_dag = 15

enable_xcom_pickling = False

sql_alchemy_pool_recycle = 570

store_serialized_dags = False

min_serialized_dag_update_interval = 30

dag_concurrencymax_active_runs_per_dag = 46

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest to check your scheduler config and see if it needs more workers.